# Year calculation not showing proper value

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I am facing a weird problem. In my .pbix file, i have a date table and a main table. I have  calculated "year wise count" in both Power BI and excel. But the problem is that, the numeric figure of the power bi file is not getting matched with the excel file's numeric figure.

I am attaching both power bi and excel file screenshots for better understanding.

[image: Power Bi file]

[image: Excel File]

I have imported the same CSV file into the power bi which i have analyzed into excel. yes, I was getting some error when i imported into the power bi, I removed those error from query editor.

so, is that the effect of getting low count than excel? or for the other reason?
Can any Power Bi guy help me out what problem is that?

Please help me to solve this problem.This is a weird kind of situation I have been facing.

Monthly Data

[image: Power Bi file]

[image: Excel file]

Comment: Probably would have been smart to show the formulas you used; even if you simply left the active cell on one of the counts so we could view the formula in the formula bar.

Comment: @sayan your total is matching up. Only the year totals are not matching. So if you are using the date field directly in the BI and Excel Pivot there is a change of getting difference. Try to split the Years into separate column and then do Pivot

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan Thanks a lot for your comment but, your idea not working..

Comment: @Sayananalytics is there any way that we can sample of data

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan The sample data is too large and this is client data.In spite of that I am trying..

Comment: @Sayananalytics the problem should be with December data if your system time format and Power BI server format are different

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan, I have added monthly data also..Please check it once..

Comment: @Sayananalytics for testing just take 2014 Feb data in excel and 2014 Feb data in Power BI and compare the date column (it would be less as its 13 records). find the missing 2 records in power BI and check the date Column

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan I am going through your idea..can you please provide your gmail id. because extending discussion over here is little more embarrassing. Mu mail id is: sanalytics2018@gmail.com..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because sufficient data to reproduce the problem has not been supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the time zone and set both excel and Power BI to same format.. I should fix the issue...